# Remove blueish coating that has leaked battery

Tags: battery

An appliance was in storage for many years, unfortunately with batteries inside. One of the batteries has leaked. How can I remove the blueish coating from the metal contact that sits inside the smaller plastic part?

[image]

Comment: old toothbrush and hot soapy water

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Comment: After removing it with a brush or screw-driver, I spray it with CRC or WD-40.  This prevents further corrosion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [brass wire brush](https://www.amazon.ca/Wire-Brush-Set-3Pcs-Stainless/dp/B09232XYYF/ref=sr_1_34?hvadid=600206458548&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9001559&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=11493493806665020474&hvtargid=kwd-304021751708&hydadcr=573_1015030531&keywords=battery%20terminal%20brush&qid=1706421355&sr=8-34) for battery terminals.  You can get battery terminal brushes but those are more for car battery terminals and

[image: brass wire brush]